# Adjoint orbit of an regular and elliptic element of $\mathrm{SP}(2n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $G = \mathrm{SP}(2n,\mathbb{R})$, $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$, $\mathfrak{h} =  \mathfrak{sp}(2m,\mathbb R) \leq \mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak q= \mathfrak h^{\perp}$. We know that $\mathfrak h$ is of the form
        \begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   \ast  & 0  & \ast  & 0 \\
   0   & 0  & 0   & 0 \\
   \ast  & 0  & \ast  & 0 \\
   0   & 0  & 0   & 0  
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align*}
    and so $\mathfrak q$ is of the form
    \begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0  & \ast & 0  & \ast \\
   \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast \\
   0  & \ast & 0  & \ast \\
   \ast & \ast & \ast & \ast 
  \end{bmatrix},
 \end{align*}
    with $0$ is a $m \times m$ matrix. Now i am interested in a condition on $m$ such that there is an elliptic and regular element in $\eta$ in $q$.
(An element is called regular if it is conjugatet to a compact subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$. An element ist called regular if the centraliser in G hase dimension rank of $\mathfrak g$ (in that case equal n).) 
Here we will have a the CSA $\mathfrak b$ given by
    \begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & D \\
   -D & 0   
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align*}
    with a diagonal matrix $D$. (You can obtain this by notice that the maximal torus in $G$ is $\mathrm U(n)$)
    There are the following known facts

- if $D'$ is regular then the diagonal elements $d_i$ in the Diagonal Block $D$ of $D'$ are never zero and pairwise different.
- the centraliser of a regular $D'$ in $\mathfrak  b$ is given by
          \begin{align*}
      C_{D'}(G) = 
      \left\{ 
       \begin{bmatrix} 0&D \\ -D&0 \end{bmatrix},
       \begin{bmatrix} D&0 \\ 0&D \end{bmatrix}
       : D \text{is diagonal}
       \right\}     
     \end{align*}
- the maximal possible rank of an element in $\mathfrak q$ is equal to $2n$ if $2m \leq n$.

For $X$ in $\mathfrak{b}$ I want to find an element $g$ in $G$, such that: $g X g^{-1} \in \mathfrak{g}$.

I have tried to compute such an element $g$, but I failed. Then I read something about Hamiltonian methods, but I could not find a helpful statement.
And of cause I had a look at adjoint-orbits, but I was not able to find anything.

So now i hope you can help me finding such an element.